# Stackoverflow Jobs company search

Tags: support, search, jobs, company

How would one search for postings from a particular company in `jobs.stackoverflow.com`?  I'm having a lot of trouble accomplishing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to search for specific companies.  However, there are a couple filters with which you can narrow your search (location and job type). From the resulting list, the search results are pretty well formatted to allow a glance at each job listing's associated company.

Answer (score 1):

Google the contents:

```
    site:jobs.stackoverflow.com php
```

The example above will search for jobs mentioning "PHP"